# Linux equivalent of VxWork's io(Global/Task)StdSet

Tags: linux, stdout, stdin, io-redirection

Do we have a Linux equivalent for the above functionality in VxWorks?
Requirement is to redirect the input and output of the serial console of a box, to a telnet session to the same box.

Thanks.